# Angular.js with Prerender

Tags: angularjs, seo, prerender

I was trying to use **Prerender** locally on port 3000, but **phantom.js** sometimes crashes and the css links gaves me many 504 http errors. I don't know how to set the links, absolute or relative? but in both ways, gaves me the same error.

My app is running on port 8000, I've added this on html file:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

I'm using the service like this, it's the right way?

http://localhost:3000/http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: have you enabled CORS?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS links causing a 504 isn't a problem. Once you proxy the requests through your webserver, it will work fine.

The correct URL to access to force the request through your middleware to the Prerender server is http://127.0.0.1:8000?_escaped_fragment_=

The middleware will then make it's own request to http://localhost:3000/http://127.0.0.1:8000 and return the page through the middleware.

As for crashing, PhantomJS can crash randomly and you don't have to worry about that when using our hosted service :)